# How do I use python to automatically change browser settings without touching?

Tags: python, android, web, auto

I need to create a web application using Python. I'm trying to get the "Ask where to save files" setting from the browser's settings to be automatically enabled when visiting the URL of this web application. I shouldn't use library tools like Selenium or Puppeeteer for this.

Can you help me in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can include a JavaScript snippet on your website that detects if the setting is disabled and provides a prompt or message suggesting the user to enable it. This won't actually change the setting but can serve as a reminder for users to do so.

Here's a simple example of how you might implement such a JavaScript snippet:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (!window.showSaveFilePicker) {
        alert('Please enable the "Ask where to save files" setting in your browser settings.');
    }
});
```

This script will check if the `showSaveFilePicker` function is available in the browser, which is supported when the "Ask where to save files" setting is enabled. If it's not available, it will display an alert prompting the user to enable the setting.

Remember, while this approach can provide guidance to users, ultimately, the decision to enable or disable browser settings rests with the user, and web applications should respect users' preferences and browser settings for security and privacy reasons.